# Python code is bug or not

Tags: python, image-processing

I try to test example all black pic it not show "mostly black" i wonder please help me

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('im.gif')
pixels = im.getdata()          # get the pixels as a flattened sequence
black_thresh = 50
nblack = 0
for pixel in pixels:
    if pixel < black_thresh:
        nblack += 1
n = len(pixels)

if (nblack / float(n)) > 0.5:
    print("mostly black")
```

Comment: Some simple debugging would find the problem here. What have you tried so far? I would be printing `pixel` to see why `pixel < black_thresh` is not evaluating to `True`

Answer (score 0):

If the image returned as tuple containing each of the color components (e.g. RGB), not a single value. You can take the average value and compare against the threshold like this:

```
for pixel in pixels:
    if sum(pixel) / len(pixel) < black_thresh:
        nblack += 1
```